# Can we edit hyperlink in Restrict editing mode in Word 2013?

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word

I am creating a form in Word 2013. I am able to restrict the text using Text form field for normal text. I also have hyperlink fields where the user needs to enter the hyperlink, and be able to click (open) the hyperlink after editing the value in the restricted form. I am not able to find out a solution where I can enable the hyperlink for restrict mode. Is there any work around for this?

Thanks, 
Adwaith

Comment: What are you trying to restrict, formatting of the hyperlink, specific values, ?

Comment: I am trying to restrict the end user from making any changes to the form. I am using restrict editing functionality for that.

Comment: What kind of control are you using for the hyperlink in the form?

Comment: Also can you clarify if you are wanting to not restrict input of the hyperlink or clicking on the hyperlink?

Comment: As of now I am using text form filed control. I didn't know what else to use. I want the end user to click and edit the hyperlink.

Comment: So it's as easy as creating a box on the form, prefilling in the default value and then protecting the form, I just did it

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Just updated my answer with a site I found that looks promissing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, now your question is more clear based upon your last comment.  I found this method - give it a try:  http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/HLinksInForms.htm

If this works let me know, I don't have time to test it out but seems promising.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. I tried as you mentioned earlier but were you able to redirect to that link on clicking it.